# Protractor-nodejs : How to capture the dynamic text from the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I want to capture 'PR001-CC001234' from the below URL using protractor node js.I know how to get the current url and store it in a variable. But need help in capturing the dyncamic text at the end of the url.

```
http://example.com/cont/abc/PR123/region/Locale/01/PR001-CC01234.html?path=/cont/abc/PR123/region/locale/01/PR001-CC01234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that

```
const url =
    "http://example.com/cont/abc/PR123/region/Locale/01/PR001-CC01234.html?path=/cont/abc/PR123/region/locale/01/PR001-CC01234";

const parts = url.split("/");
console.log(parts[parts.length - 1]);
//PR001-CC01234
```